# Getting error: from(java.time.Instant) in Date cannot be applied to (org.threeten.bp.instant)

Tags: java, type-mismatch, date-conversion, java.util.date, threetenbp

I am trying to convert the `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate` to `java.util.Date` and I am getting the error mentioned in the question title.

I am using following for conversion:

```
Date.from(currentDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

**Error:**

```
from(java.time.Instant) in Date cannot be applied to (org.threeten.bp.instant)
```

I am trying to convert

1. LocalDate to Date
2. Date to LocalDate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is basically correct and would have worked with `java.time.LocalDate`, only not with the implementation of the same class in `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate`. So your options are two:

1. Change all of your imports to use `java.time` instead of `org.threeten.bp` and stop using the backport.
2. Use `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` for conversions between legacy date-time classes and the classes in ThreeTen Backport.

Example of option 2.:

```
    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/Whitehorse"));
    Date d = DateTimeUtils.toDate(
            currentDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    System.out.println("" + currentDate + " was converted to " + d);
```

When running on my computer just now this snippet printed:

> 2019-06-25 was converted to Tue Jun 25 00:00:00 CEST 2019

`DateTimeUtils` also has a `toInstant(Date)` method for the opposite conversion.

**Link:** [`DateTimeUtils` documentation](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html)

Comment: I switched to `JodaTime` and completely removed the `org.threeten.bp` library. But thanks for the answer. I will try it and if it works I will accept the answer.

Comment: Glad you got something to work. Joda-Time officially recommends: *Users are now asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).* So you should prefer java.time (either built-in or through the backport). More on [the Joda-Time home page](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/).